# Registering Services in a module and including dependent modules in jasmine

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine

Started to write unit test cases using jasmine.But Stuck in the middle

I have a module called "app" it is declared in  one js file with config and run blocks,,,in the same file, while creating a module, i mention its dependeny modules as well...

**app.js**

```
   var app; ------> it is declared as a global variable
   app=angular.module('app,['ngSanitize','Deepak']);
app.run(['$rootScope', '$window', '$anchorScroll', '$timeout', 'resources', function($rootScope, $window, $anchorScroll, $timeout, resources)
```

Then in other js files where controllers,factory,services and directives are created,below lines were used

```
angular.module('app').factory
angular.module('app').controller
angular.module('app').service
angular.module('app').filter
```

So it means am adding the controller,filter,factory and service to the existing module called 'app'

Now am going to create a unit test case, am loading the module as below

**DemoToTheTeam.js**

```
beforeEach(function () {    
angular.module('app');
});
```

Does the above line means, it also loading 'Deepak' and 'ngSanitize' module as well(As it was declared as a dependency earlier at the top)

And no matter how many times i run giving the relative paths of all the js files in my application after angular-mock files in the karma.conf.js..It is still not able to inject the factory service

It simply shows Unknown provider with the service name..Along with declaration error as below

```
 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: InformationServiceProvider <- InformationService
 http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/unpr?p0=ServiceProvider%20%3C-%20InformationService
     at C:/jasmine/project/node_modules/angular/angular.js:68:12
     at C:/jasmine/project/node_modules/angular/angular.js:4501:19
     at Object.getService [as get] (C:/jasmine/project/node_modules/angular/angular.js:4654:39)
     at C:/jasmine/project/node_modules/angular/angular.js:4506:45
     at Object.getService [as get] (C:/jasmine/project/node_modules/angular/angular.js:4654:39)
     at Object.<anonymous> (C:/jasmine/project/tests/DemoToTheTeam.js:79:25)
     at Object.invoke (C:/jasmine/project/node_modules/angular/angular.js:4708:19)
     at Object.workFn (C:/jasmine/project/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3071:20)
 Error: Declaration Location
     at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (C:/jasmine/project/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3033:25)
     at Suite.<anonymous> (C:/jasmine/project/tests/DemoToTheTeam.js:78:12)
     at C:/jasmine/project/tests/DemoToTheTeam.js:2:1
```

Am confused on why my service is not recognized and mocked??? Does any1 have any clue on why this is happening, even though i specify the correct relative path of the js files in karma file ??

In some posts , i have seen that even the services,controller and directives that are loaded in the test case can be printed in console

```
angular.module('app')['_invokeQueue'].forEach(function(value){ 
console.log(value[1] + ": " + value[2][0]);
})
```

But i see only a few services that loaded and not all services are loaded, but all are created with angular.module('app').factory syntax -->created in existing module..couldn't figure out why certain services are not loaded even though i have declared its relative path in the karma file

**This is my factory service(LanguagesService .js)**

```
angular.module('app').factory('LanguagesService', function(){
  var lng = {}, 
    _languages = ['en', 'es', 'fr'];

  lng.get = function() {
    return _languages;
  }

  return lng;
});
```

Am creating the above factory service in a existing module

**spec file**

```
describe('Test LanguagesService ', function () {

var mockService;

beforeEach(function () {

    angular.module('app');

});

beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {

    mockService = $injector.get('LanguagesService');

}));


it('Should call foo fn', function() {

    mockService.getmessages();   
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Q. -** Does the above line means, it also loading 'Deepak' and 'ngSanitize' module as well(As it was declared as a dependency earlier at the top)

**Ans. -** Yes. It will load all these modules automatically. The problem is, you haven't injected the service InformationService in the test spec file for which you're writing the test cases. That's what the error is telling.

I suggest you have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37783376/2622292) for the appropriate syntax.

**UPDATE:**

As far as your spec file is concerned, try this syntax.

```
describe('Service: InformationService', function () {

    var InformationService;
    beforeEach(module('app'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_InformationService_) {
        InformationService = _InformationService_;
    }));


    it('Should call foo fn', function() {
        InformationService.getmessages();
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes Added the spec file

Comment: Earlier i got the name of the Factory service in the error log..No am getting  Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: resourcesProvider <- resources ------> without the Factory service name

Comment: I have run and config blocks....Should those dependencies also be mocked before loading modules?

Comment: Done updating the question with run and config blocks

Comment: It's not there in the question. Bro, I suggest you first read the documentation on Jasmine's website or probably follow a tutorial.